# Null Pointer Exception at JLabel Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

I want to create JLabel with icon in for loop.

Here is my code;

```
 final JLabel[] box = new JLabel[27]; 
 for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
     int j = 1;
     String r = "case" + j + ".png";
     box[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(r)));
     j++;
 }
```

names of icons are like `case1.png`, `case2.png`;....

But there is a null point exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at Game.<init>(Game.java:185) at Game.main(Game.java:243) here are the exceptions
```

Is it just because I did not create names of icons truely? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you initialised `box`?

Comment: for a quick reply check if your box is initialised. you should post your complete error log here for us to track the null pointer.

Comment: final JLabel[] box= new JLabel[27]; I initialised it like that is there any problem?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at Game.<init>(Game.java:185)
 at Game.main(Game.java:243) here are the exceptions

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with your problem, but do note that j is always equal to 1, so all icons will be initialized from "case1.png".

Comment: The code you have posted is not where the exception is occurring.  Please edit your question to include the constructor of your `Game` class.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring ALL your `JLabel`'s name as `case1.png` since at the start of your `for loop`, you are assigning `int j = 1;`

Your code should look like this:

```
 final JLabel[] box = new JLabel[27]; 
 int j = 1; //should be outside the for loop
 for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
     String r = "case" + j + ".png";
     box[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(r)));
     j++;
 }
```

Comment: thanx :) it work but I found the problem. in for loop instead of i<25 i should do i<26 :DDDDD